# What's the best way to not display default input styles?

Tags: css

Does anyone know a nice way of hiding default styles for all inputs, such a text, textarea, range, radio buttons / checkboxes etc?

I normally include the following code into my projects:

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
textarea,
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Which works greats for inputs such as text, teaxtarea and select, but what about the others?

I would normally use the following code for radio and checkboxes:

**CSS**

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
appearence: none;
```

But is this really the best way?

Finally onto Range, this is what I would normally use:

**CSS**

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
    width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. Not great for accessibility. */
}
```

**Accessibility:**

From a design point of view no many people like the default outline you get when you focus on an input, I prefer as so do others to style the outline accordingly with the design of the project. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `normalize css` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response Antoine but normalize aims to make elements more consistent across browsers, I'm wanting to style the inputs according to each project I'm working on. Hence why I'm trying to hide the default styles., not just make them consistent.

Comment: I do not get it. Why don't you just style your elements how you like them? Why the hassle to reset all OS specific styling, just to aply your own? I mean, just apply your own and do less work?! Please explain it to me, I am ignorant. ;)

Comment: Then look at a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/)

Comment: @PaulRoub I'm already using Eric Meyer’s reset, but this really doesn't focus on inputs, intact I don't even think inputs are included in the reset at all.

Comment: @Jordan: why not just overwrite these properties?

Comment: Form elements have always been rather difficult to style. Some elements have parts that have to be there and therefore cannot be style easily (e.g. `<select>`) and others are simply too complex (e.g. `date` or `color`). While we wait for the shadow DOM there is not very much that can be done. You can create your own elements, with Javascript and such, but then you will anger mobile users... I would recommend that you use the native elements, style them so they look reasonable in all browsers, and just accept that there is not much to do about it.

Comment: @Professor.CSS What do you men exactly?

Comment: much like what the css-reset does, overwrite the styles of the elements you don't want. For example, if you don't want any textare to have a border, set `textarea{border:none}` in your css

Comment: @Professor.CSS If I were to approach it like that, I would have to do each property for each element, that just seems like a really complicated / long way of doing it.

Comment: @Jordan: there aren't that many elements, and there are only so many elements you would need to use. What exactly do you think a css-reset does? Or the normalise css? or even what you 'normally' do?

Comment: @Professor.CSS I understand what you're saying, and I know how to already do what you're saying. But in my question I was asking if anyone knew a similar (easier) way of doing this for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You really have almost everything you need, at least for desktop browsers.

For iOS textboxes, you'll want to add a couple extras:

```
input[type="text"],input[type="email"],input[type="url"],textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none; //important!
    border: none;
}
```

As for the radio buttons, using CSS transformations for purposes other than 3d, viewport, and animations could be argued as bad practice. One could get away with it on an average form; however, having a large form with dozens of inputs one would notice a huge lag if viewed on a lower-end device. This is due to CSS3 using graphics acceleration. Hardware acceleration is usually a good thing, if used right. For instance, 3d viewport animation. They have less lag when accelerated because all the DOM trees/layers are formed into a vector and sent to the graphics card. Do realize that *computers* have graphics cards, but with more and more people using tablets and such, the graphics cards don't have all that glory. ***Anyway,*** here's what you should do for radios instead, which will be more cross-browser as well (CSS2):

```
input[type=radio] {
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -28px;
  padding-left : 28px;
  background   : url('radio.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  line-height  : 24px;
}
```

Using the negative margin positive padding trick, you can push the old radio control off the edge and use a background image. Be sure to use a `<label>` with these! To ensure they remain clickable on all browsers.

That's all I got, really there are a lot of methods out there, and my answer here surely isn't definitive.

Enjoy!